# Snowflake Python 3 Connection Closed Error

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The error posted to the console captured in the try except block is `250002 (08003): Connection is closed`

The query for the 'select_new_contacts' is executed but the queries 'contact_created' and 'delete_contact_working_list' are not executed on the database.  Manually run on the database they complete without error.  The snowflake package 'snowflake-connector-python' is version 2.2.4

snowflake_operations.py

```
import enums
import contact_operations
import snowflake.connector
from snowflake.connector import DictCursor
from snowflake.connector.converter_null import SnowflakeNoConverterToPython


connection = snowflake.connector.connect(
                user=enums.SnowflakeCredentials.USER.value,
                password=enums.SnowflakeCredentials.PASSWORD.value,
                account=enums.SnowflakeCredentials.ACCOUNT.value,
                warehouse=enums.SnowflakeCredentials.WAREHOUSE.value,
                database=enums.SnowflakeCredentials.DATABASE.value,
                schema=enums.SnowflakeCredentials.SCHEMA.value,
                converter_class=SnowflakeNoConverterToPython,
                role=enums.SnowflakeCredentials.ROLE.value
                )


def select_new_contacts():

    record_set = []
    try:
        sql_select_query = enums.DatabaseQueries.SELECT_NEW_CONTACTS.value.format(
            limit_number=int(enums.BatchThreadLimits.SELECT_LIMIT_NUMBER.value)
        )

        cur_select = connection.cursor(DictCursor).execute(sql_select_query)
        ret = cur_select.fetchmany(int(enums.BatchThreadLimits.FETCH_MANY_NUMBER.value))

        while len(ret) > 0:
            for rec in ret:
                record_set.append(rec)

            ret = cur_select.fetchmany(int(enums.BatchThreadLimits.FETCH_MANY_NUMBER.value))

        return record_set
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        connection.close()


def contact_created(query_values):

    # try:
    #     cur = connection.cursor()
    # except Exception as e:
    #     raise Exception(e)

    sql_query = enums.DatabaseQueries.NEW_CONTACT_CREATED.value.format(
        synced_employee_id=query_values['employee_id'],
        synced_intercom_primary_key=query_values['intercom_primary_key'])

    try:
        connection.cursor().execute(sql_query)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('this contact_created is the except block')
    finally:
        connection.cursor().close()


def delete_contact_working_list(employee_id):
    # cur = connection.cursor()
    sql_query = enums.DatabaseQueries.REMOVE_FROM_WORKING_LIST.value.format(delete_employee_id=employee_id)

    try:
        connection.cursor().execute(sql_query)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        connection.cursor().close()
```

Comment: replacing the connection.close()  / connection.cursor().close() with pass solves the immediate problem (so the queries execute) but leaving open connections seems wrong and sloppy

Comment: This is basic connection pooling.You either keep pool alive or close it in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 250002 (08003): Connection is closed

The central issue is that you have only a single connection object, and closing that after running one statement will cause it to become unavailable for all subsequent statements being executed.

> replacing the connection.close() with pass solves the immediate problem
>
> but leaving open connections seems wrong and sloppy

It is true that you shouldn't leave an open connection, but you can pick when to close it based on what you are trying to do.

For instance you can pick to close the connection only after all statements have executed using the same `try…finally` approach or using a [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#handling-exceptions) (`with`).

An example construct of the program with such changes will look like below (I've included both options as different main functions):

```py
import […]

# Do not close connection within these functions

def select_new_contacts(connection, …):
  […]

def contact_created(connection, …):
  […]

def delete_contact_working_list(connection, …):
  […]

def main_with_try_finally():
  "This explicitly closes the connection via a finally block"

  connection = snowflake.connector.connect(…)

  try:

    select_new_contacts(connection, …)
    contact_created(connection, …)
    delete_contact_working_list(connection, …)

  finally:

    connection.close()

def main_with_context_management():
  "This auto-closes the connection once the whole block completes"

  with snowflake.connector.connect(…) as connection:

    select_new_contacts(connection, …)
    contact_created(connection, …)
    delete_contact_working_list(connection, …)
```

If you need a connection pool so you can execute queries from many threads over concurrent connections, Snowflake also supports [use of SQLAlchemy](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#opening-and-closing-a-connection) which provides connection objects from a managed pool.

Comment: We went with SQLAlchemy